Error playing audio: PlatformException(WebAudioError, Player has not yet been created or has already been disposed., null, null)
Im making a mobile flutter project, this is a opening page of my project, it contains a short videop opening and audio. but the audio won't playing. only the video. and at my terminal says Error playing audio: PlatformException(WebAudioError, Player has not yet been created or has already been disposed., null, null) here my code


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:abel/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoController;
  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize the video player
    _videoController = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/images/splashscreen.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
        _videoController.play();
      });

    // Initialize the audio player
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    _playAudio();

    // Navigate to HomeScreen after a delay
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 5000), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
      );
    });

    // System UI settings
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [
      SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
    ]);

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ));

    // Lock orientation to landscape
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
  }

  Future<void> _playAudio() async {
    try {
      await _audioPlayer.play(AssetSource('assets/audio/splashsound.mp3'));
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error playing audio: $error');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoController.dispose();
    _audioPlayer.dispose();

    // Reset orientation
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              FractionallySizedBox(
                widthFactor: 1.0,
                heightFactor: 1.0,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_videoController),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}




Please provide working, executable code that exemplifies minimum reproducibility.

Don't include assets in path. You have change it to :
_audioPlayer.play(AssetSource('audio/splashsound.mp3'));

